# Conditional count in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe (df) with three columns like so:

**Structure:**

```
id id1 age
A1 a1  32
A1 a2  45
A1 a3  45
A1 a4  12
A2 b1  15
A2 b5  34
A2 b64 17
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id count count1
A1 4     1
A2 3     2
```

**Logic:**

- Column "count" is the number of times "id" is repeated
- Column "count1" is the number of rows where age is less than 21

**Current Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
df_summarized <- df %>% 
                     group_by(id) >%> 
                     summarise(count = n(),count1 = count(age<21))
```

**Problem:**

```
Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to do the `sum`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(count = n(),count1 = sum(age < 21))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
#     id count count1
#  <chr> <int>  <int>
#1    A1     4      1
#2    A2     3      2
```

as `count` applies to `data.frame` or `tbl_df` and not in a single column inside the `summarise`

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(count = .N, count1 = sum(age < 21)), id]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
cbind(count = rowSums(table(df[-2])), count1 = as.vector(rowsum(+(df$age < 21), df$id)))
#   count count1
#A1     4      1
#A2     3      2
```

Or using `aggregate` based on the `sum`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(age~id, df, FUN =
            function(x) c(count = length(x), count1 = sum(x<21))))
```

NOTE: All the above methods give the dataset with proper columns.  This will be especially noted in `aggregate`.  That is the reason the output column i.e. a matrix is converted to proper columns with `do.call(data.frame`

Answer (score 4):

With base R, we can use `aggregate` to find number of rows for each group (`id`) as well as number of rows with value less than 21

```
aggregate(age~id, df, function(x) c(count = length(x), 
                                                   count1 = length(x[x  < 21])))

#  id age.count age.count1
#1 A1         4          1
#2 A2         3          2
```